# Getting rid of transitive relations in a graphviz input file

Tags: graphviz

I have relatively complex graphviz input files that contain transitive relations. Unfortunately these make the output overly complex without adding any additional information.

Is there any simple way to strip these transitive relations from the input/output.

Example input:

```
digraph main { 
subgraph cluster_Session_0 {
color = black;
label = "Session_0";
 "Batch_0_0";
}
subgraph cluster_Session_1 {
color = black;
label = "Session_1";
 "Batch_1_0" "Batch_1_1" "Batch_1_2" "Batch_1_3" "Batch_1_4";
}
subgraph cluster_Session_2 {
color = black;
label = "Session_2";
 "Batch_2_0" "Batch_2_1" "Batch_2_2" "Batch_2_3";
}
subgraph cluster_Session_3 {
color = black;
label = "Session_3";
 "Batch_3_0";
}
subgraph cluster_Session_4 {
color = black;
label = "Session_4";
 "Batch_4_0";
}
subgraph cluster_Session_5 {
color = black;
label = "Session_5";
 "Batch_5_0";
}
subgraph cluster_Session_6 {
color = black;
label = "Session_6";
 "Batch_6_0";
}
subgraph cluster_Session_7 {
color = black;
label = "Session_7";
 "Batch_7_0";
}
subgraph cluster_Session_8 {
color = black;
label = "Session_8";
 "Batch_8_0";
}
subgraph cluster_Session_9 {
color = black;
label = "Session_9";
 "Batch_9_0";
}
subgraph cluster_Session_10 {
color = black;
label = "Session_10";
 "Batch_10_0";
}
subgraph cluster_Session_11 {
color = black;
label = "Session_11";
 "Batch_11_0";
}
subgraph cluster_Session_12 {
color = black;
label = "Session_12";
 "Batch_12_0";
}
subgraph cluster_Session_13 {
color = black;
label = "Session_13";
 "Batch_13_0";
}
subgraph cluster_Session_14 {
color = black;
label = "Session_14";
 "Batch_14_0";
}
"Batch_0_0" -> "Batch_1_0";
"Batch_0_0" -> "Batch_1_0";
"Batch_1_0" -> "Batch_1_1";
"Batch_1_1" -> "Batch_1_2";
"Batch_1_2" -> "Batch_1_3";
"Batch_1_3" -> "Batch_1_4";
"Batch_1_4" -> "Batch_2_0";
"Batch_0_0" -> "Batch_2_0";
"Batch_1_4" -> "Batch_2_0";
"Batch_2_0" -> "Batch_2_1";
"Batch_2_1" -> "Batch_2_2";
"Batch_2_2" -> "Batch_2_3";
"Batch_2_3" -> "Batch_3_0";
"Batch_0_0" -> "Batch_3_0";
"Batch_1_4" -> "Batch_3_0";
"Batch_2_3" -> "Batch_3_0";
"Batch_3_0" -> "Batch_4_0";
"Batch_0_0" -> "Batch_4_0";
"Batch_1_4" -> "Batch_4_0";
"Batch_2_3" -> "Batch_4_0";
"Batch_3_0" -> "Batch_4_0";
"Batch_4_0" -> "Batch_5_0";
"Batch_0_0" -> "Batch_5_0";
"Batch_1_4" -> "Batch_5_0";
"Batch_2_3" -> "Batch_5_0";
"Batch_3_0" -> "Batch_5_0";
"Batch_5_0" -> "Batch_6_0";
"Batch_0_0" -> "Batch_6_0";
"Batch_1_4" -> "Batch_6_0";
"Batch_2_3" -> "Batch_6_0";
"Batch_3_0" -> "Batch_6_0";
"Batch_6_0" -> "Batch_7_0";
"Batch_0_0" -> "Batch_7_0";
"Batch_1_4" -> "Batch_7_0";
"Batch_2_3" -> "Batch_7_0";
"Batch_3_0" -> "Batch_7_0";
"Batch_4_0" -> "Batch_7_0";
"Batch_5_0" -> "Batch_7_0";
"Batch_6_0" -> "Batch_7_0";
"Batch_7_0" -> "Batch_8_0";
"Batch_0_0" -> "Batch_8_0";
"Batch_1_4" -> "Batch_8_0";
"Batch_2_3" -> "Batch_8_0";
"Batch_3_0" -> "Batch_8_0";
"Batch_4_0" -> "Batch_8_0";
"Batch_5_0" -> "Batch_8_0";
"Batch_6_0" -> "Batch_8_0";
"Batch_7_0" -> "Batch_8_0";
"Batch_8_0" -> "Batch_9_0";
"Batch_0_0" -> "Batch_9_0";
"Batch_1_4" -> "Batch_9_0";
"Batch_2_3" -> "Batch_9_0";
"Batch_3_0" -> "Batch_9_0";
"Batch_4_0" -> "Batch_9_0";
"Batch_5_0" -> "Batch_9_0";
"Batch_6_0" -> "Batch_9_0";
"Batch_7_0" -> "Batch_9_0";
"Batch_8_0" -> "Batch_9_0";
"Batch_9_0" -> "Batch_10_0";
"Batch_0_0" -> "Batch_10_0";
"Batch_1_4" -> "Batch_10_0";
"Batch_2_3" -> "Batch_10_0";
"Batch_3_0" -> "Batch_10_0";
"Batch_4_0" -> "Batch_10_0";
"Batch_5_0" -> "Batch_10_0";
"Batch_6_0" -> "Batch_10_0";
"Batch_7_0" -> "Batch_10_0";
"Batch_8_0" -> "Batch_10_0";
"Batch_9_0" -> "Batch_10_0";
"Batch_10_0" -> "Batch_11_0";
"Batch_0_0" -> "Batch_11_0";
"Batch_1_4" -> "Batch_11_0";
"Batch_2_3" -> "Batch_11_0";
"Batch_3_0" -> "Batch_11_0";
"Batch_4_0" -> "Batch_11_0";
"Batch_5_0" -> "Batch_11_0";
"Batch_6_0" -> "Batch_11_0";
"Batch_7_0" -> "Batch_11_0";
"Batch_8_0" -> "Batch_11_0";
"Batch_9_0" -> "Batch_11_0";
"Batch_10_0" -> "Batch_11_0";
"Batch_11_0" -> "Batch_12_0";
"Batch_0_0" -> "Batch_12_0";
"Batch_1_4" -> "Batch_12_0";
"Batch_2_3" -> "Batch_12_0";
"Batch_3_0" -> "Batch_12_0";
"Batch_4_0" -> "Batch_12_0";
"Batch_5_0" -> "Batch_12_0";
"Batch_6_0" -> "Batch_12_0";
"Batch_7_0" -> "Batch_12_0";
"Batch_8_0" -> "Batch_12_0";
"Batch_9_0" -> "Batch_12_0";
"Batch_10_0" -> "Batch_12_0";
"Batch_12_0" -> "Batch_13_0";
"Batch_0_0" -> "Batch_13_0";
"Batch_1_4" -> "Batch_13_0";
"Batch_2_3" -> "Batch_13_0";
"Batch_3_0" -> "Batch_13_0";
"Batch_4_0" -> "Batch_13_0";
"Batch_5_0" -> "Batch_13_0";
"Batch_6_0" -> "Batch_13_0";
"Batch_7_0" -> "Batch_13_0";
"Batch_8_0" -> "Batch_13_0";
"Batch_9_0" -> "Batch_13_0";
"Batch_10_0" -> "Batch_13_0";
"Batch_11_0" -> "Batch_13_0";
"Batch_12_0" -> "Batch_13_0";
"Batch_13_0" -> "Batch_14_0";
"Batch_0_0" -> "Batch_14_0";
"Batch_1_4" -> "Batch_14_0";
"Batch_2_3" -> "Batch_14_0";
"Batch_3_0" -> "Batch_14_0";
"Batch_4_0" -> "Batch_14_0";
"Batch_5_0" -> "Batch_14_0";
"Batch_6_0" -> "Batch_14_0";
"Batch_7_0" -> "Batch_14_0";
"Batch_8_0" -> "Batch_14_0";
"Batch_9_0" -> "Batch_14_0";
"Batch_10_0" -> "Batch_14_0";
"Batch_11_0" -> "Batch_14_0";
"Batch_12_0" -> "Batch_14_0";
}
```

Example output:
[image]

Comment: Does the [tred](http://graphviz.org/pdf/tred.1.pdf) command of the GraphViz tools do what you want?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Given the example dot source from the question in a file named `test.dot` the `tred` tool (transitive reduction filter for directed graphs) from the GraphViz command line tools reduces it to a linear graph with the following command line:

```
tred test.dot | dot -T png > test.png
```

Resulting image:

[image]

Comment: Any higher-performance alternatives to tred, particularly for nodes with long names?